# Hidden sidebar, expand my viewport, how to change it?

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar, hamburger-menu

I've made hamburger menu with sidebar list for mobile with some js. This is code:

```
<button class="hamburger">
            <span class="hamburger__box">
                <span class="hamburger__inner"></span>
            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation__list">
                <a href="zatrudnij-programiste-webowego"><li class="navigation__item">O mnie</li></a>
                <a href="zatrudnij-programiste-webowego"><li class="navigation__item">Oferta</li></a>
                <a href="html-css-js-php-bootstrap-seo-wordpress"><li class="navigation__item">Technologie</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li class="navigation__item 7" >Kontakt</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

There is js:

```
<script>
            
            const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
            const nav = document.querySelector('.navigation');
            

            const handleClick = () => {
            hamburger.classList.toggle('hamburger--active');
            nav.classList.toggle('navigation--active');

            }
            hamburger.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        </script>
```

And css (part of):

```
.hamburger
{
    width:100%;
    height: 72px;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:0;
}

.hamburger, .navigation

{
    transition: transform .3s .1s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger--active

{
    transform: translateX(-120px); 
}

.hamburger__box

{
    width:100px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;

}

.hamburger__inner

{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #ff7300;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
    transition: background-color.1s .2s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger__inner::before
{
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-20px;
    transition: transform.2s .2s ease-in-out;

}

.hamburger__inner::after
{
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:20px;
    transition: transform.2s .2s ease-in-out;

}
.navigation
{
    height:45vh;
    font-size:25px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: #ff7300;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    transform: translateX(200px);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.navigation--active
{
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
.navigation__item
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}
.navigation__item
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:#fff;
    a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

Idea is simple to move sidebar menu out of screen but then horizontal scroll is showing, I only test this in device mode in Firefox so i don't know how it will looks like on my phone (but i suppose the scroll doesn't disapear in magic way). I've also tried with `display:none;` for inactive list but this command doesn't support animation. It's possible to fix this idea or it is just wrong by design?

Comment: you can use `overflow-x:hidden` to hide horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Please also add the style for your sidebar.

Comment: @RayeesAC i missed .navigation in code which i paste here so i added overflow-x and read about it on developers.mozilla and w3schools but it don't change nothing. I have a feeling that overflow-x:hidden  hiding elements which sticking out of the conteiner, and also think i just made container for that list that's why it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @michaelT added at the end of code

Comment: Should the sidebar should be ````absolute````? Or do you want to have a ````fixed```` sidebar? A ````fixed```` sidebar i s what you see in the most cases, so it stays on its position even when the body is scrolled.

Comment: @michaelT how simple it seems right now, I dont mind about absolute but since fixed solved my problem, i prefer fixed :D

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use The overflow Property

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

This is to remove scroll horizontally at it to the body style sheet.

Comment: Yeah it works, silly me added overflow-x:hidden to my sidebar class

Comment: your solution was good for firefox and mobile view (ctrl+shift+m) coz scroll disapear, but when i testing site live on my mobile device the scroll still was there and I was able to see this sidelist hidden behind right edge

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a sidebar with `position: fixed`, especially for mobile views.
So the position of the sidebar is not affected by the bodys scroll position:

The animation to show/hide the sidebar can be done with `left` property or `transform: translateX`. Here is an example. Note that I saved the `width` of the sidebar using a `root` variable.

```js
let burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger-menu');
let sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
burgerMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar__active');
});
```

```css
:root{
  --sidebar-width: 120px;
}

body{
  magin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #dedede;
}

.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--sidebar-width));
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transition: left 1s linear;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.sidebar__active{
  left: 0px;
}

.burger-menu{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 72px;
  font-size:36px;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-right: 64px;
  padding-left: 64px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
  Sidebar
</nav>

<button id="burger-menu" class="burger-menu">Toggle sidebar</button>

<section class="content">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</section>
```